# Caliburn.Micro implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, validation, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to find an elegant solution to implement `INotifiyDataErrorInfo` with Caliburn.Micro MVVM framework.

I want to limit the amount of code that will be repeated in each VM that needs to implement the validation. 
I started by writing a class that inherits `Screen` and implements `INotifiyDataErrorInfo`. It works correctly and all is fine, until I need validation on a VM that is not a `Screen`, but a `Conductor`.

Of course, I could make a class that inherits `Conductor` and implements `INotifyDataErrorInfo` but that's quite annoying as I would have to basically make my own version of all "base" classes of Caliburn.Micro.

One solution I had was to keep the `Screen` base class and create a `IValidator` interface that I would inject into my VM, something like this:

```
public interface IValidator<T> where T : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    void Validates(T instance);

    IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName);
    bool HasErrors { get; }

    void Validate();
    void ValidateProperty<TValue>(TValue value, string propertyName = null);
    void ValidateProperty<TValue, TProperty>(TValue value, Expression<Func<TProperty>> property);
}
```

It will then used in the VM in this way.

```
public class CreateCarViewModel : Conductor<CreateCarViewModel>.Collection.OneActive, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
   private readonly IValidator<CreateCarViewModel> validator;

   public CreateExperimentViewModel(IValidator<CreateCarViewModel> validator)
   {
       this.DisplayName = "Select a car";

       this.validator = validator;
       this.validator.Validates(this);
   }

   [Required]
   public string CarName
   {
       get
       {
           return this.carName;
       }
       set
       {
           if (this.carName != value)
           {
               this.carName = value;

               this.validator.ValidateProperty(value, () => this.CarName);
               this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CarName);
           }
       }
   }

   public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

   public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
   {
       return this.validator.GetErrors(propertyName);
   }

   public bool HasErrors
   {
       get { return this.validator.HasErrors; }
   }

   ...

}
```

This works pretty nicely, as it is very simple to implement the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` in the VMs, but the issue I have is triggering the `ErrorChanged` event. It must be triggered by the implementation of the `IValidator` as he is the one who knows when the errors have changed, and of course he cannot trigger directly.

One idea I have was to have an event in the `IValidator` and subscribe to it in the VM so that it can trigger its own event, but I find that it makes a lot of code for nothing.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wireup code is not excessive is it, if you have the IValidator expose the same event as the VM, eg:

```
    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public void Validate()
    {
        if (ErrorsChanged != null)
            ErrorsChanged(instance, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs("someProperty"));
    }
```

and in the VM:

```
 validator.ErrorsChanged += (sender, args) => ErrorsChanged(sender, args);
```

But I guess you already answered your own question without telling us ;)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I ended up doing. I thought it would be way more complicated when writing the question. The only thing I don't like with my result is that I have to implement my own "Validating" version of a lot of Caliburn.Micro's class that derives from PropertyChangedBase (I have ValidatingPropertyChangedBase, ValidatingScreen, ValidatingConductorCollectionOneActive for now...)

Comment: Yes, we had the same issue. I got rid of the ValidateProperty method by adding a custom Validate attribute to each property that needed validating. I store the validator in the base class and when we call PropertyChanged it knows to call the validator. The attribute also has a DisplayName overload so the user doesn't see property name. To be honest, I'm tempted to just implement all the validation attributes from MVC in my validator base class. I guess someone already did that though.

Comment: Thanks for the code, by the way, it's a useful, testable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small plugin for CM to enable fluent builder-style validation. Maybe it will help you. Feel free to use it: https://github.com/AIexandr/Caliburn.Micro.Validation
Example of usage:

```
public class PaymentEditorViewModel() : ValidatingScreen
{
  public PaymentEditorViewModel()
  {
    AddValidationRule(() => PaymentSum).Condition(() => PaymentSum <= 0).Message("Please enter payment sum");
  }

  #region PaymentSum property
  decimal _PaymentSum;
  public decimal PaymentSum
  {
    get
    {
      return _PaymentSum;
    }
    set
    {
      _PaymentSum = value;
      NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PaymentSum);
    }
  }
  #endregion
}
```

Comment: That's pretty cool, thanks for sharing! I'll have a look at it.